# Node passwordless login from seperate device

Tags: node.js, cookies, passwords

I am using the nodejs passwordless (https://passwordless.net/) library for passwordless login. One of the features is a link sent in an email that opens the logged in page in the browser. Works great.
What I would like to do is have it so that if the link is clicked on, on one device, and the page that the user entered their email is open on another device, then that page would also login, using some cookie or something.

The reason for this is to add even more convenience to the concept of passwordless login - by being able to click on the link on a phone you dont have to go to another tab in your browser on your computer.

Do people have any other thoughts about making passwordless login as seamless as possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't possible because it "begs the question" that authentication is designed to answer.  Namely, "Is this client application operating on behalf of a user registered with this service?"

Let's walk it through:

**Device 1**

1. The user visits your website for the first time.
2. The service sets a cookie with the id of a new, unique session on your website (or app).
3. The user submits their email in a form.
4. The user receives an email with an URL+token, token courtesy of Passwordless.
5. The user clicks on the URL.
6. The service validates the token, again via Passwordless, *and marks Device 1's session as authenticated*.

The effect of this workflow (esp. steps 3-5) is to let you infer a vital piece of information: that whoever is contacting this website has control of the provided email address.  Now let's look at another device.

**Device 2**

1. Some user visits your website for the first time.
2. The service sets a cookie with the id of a new, unique session on your website.

So we have a device, with a cookie, but now what?  Literally anyone in the world could have just pointed a web browser or app at your site.  We need more information.  So we could ask for an email address:

3. The user submits their email in a form.

Now we have an email from Device 2.  But we have no idea whether this is legitimately the user who controls this email address.  It could easily be an attacker, someone after your service, after this user, or maybe just a spammer with some bots.

It's not until we get to step 6 in the original workflow that we have enough information to know whether this device is being used by the same user as on Device 1.  But once we've gone that far, the user has just logged into Device 2!  At that point there's no need to "log them in automatically" from Device 1 because they just authenticated themselves on Device 2.

Comment: I see exactly what you are saying, but this is basically what web.whatsapp does isn't it, with QR codes - I scan a QR code on my phone and it logs me in on my computer. Why can't I do the equivelent, but with a token in my mail box? I know the device which requested the token so I just auth that device (using an open socket or something?)

Comment: WhatsApp Web is an example of using an authenticated device & application to authorize another device.  Plain-text email isn't authenticated.  So you'd at very least need to ensure that the link in the "Authorize Device 2?" email is only valid when opened in a browser already authenticated to the same user, basically like an OAuth app registration workflow.  This all seems far more cumbersome than just having the user click the link in email on Device 2. One way or the other, I'd suggest an attempted solution here will need a professional security audit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be possible.

I don't have a cooked recipe but some direction for your exploration could be :

- You need to set allow reuse tokens before setting your token store. This can be done by `allowTokenReuse:true`.
- Somehow make sure first 2 or more devices gets the same session. This could be done by sharing sessions.

  - A more solid advice would be using sockets to track connected clients. You may want to check the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488806/node-js-socket-io-keep-track-of-clients)
  - I found a awesome article to share and sync sessions between socket.io and express. Check [here](http://mono.software/2014/08/25/Sharing-sessions-between-SocketIO-and-Express-using-Redis/)

Pls share your explorations of you can. I am thinking to use sockets aswell.